# Understanding set notation and which well known set is this?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

*First of all I wan't to ask if my understanding of the notation is correct, and later on, what well known set is this one?*

*I'm not allowed to embed images yet, so here is the link to the set:*

[image: Well known Set]

**For elements (n) of natural numbers set (N) such that (elements are bigger than one) and (for all elements x,y in natural numbers set)**, not sure how to transition in to the brackets, but I understand it as follows, **[(elements x,y multiplied together are equal to the elements we are looking for initialy (n), this implies (=>) that always either x or y are equal to 1 in every case belonging to the set we are looking for)].**

*Also there is an appendix that (IN THIS COURSE MATERIAL) the natural set begins from 1 and not from 0, to get rid of all the confusions that this may imply.
Thanks.*

Comment: Looks like the primes to me.

Comment: @XanderHenderson this implies that I misunderstood the notation?

Comment: the brackets are to be read as the stuff that happens after you declare who the "actors" are:

For all $n>1$ and for all $x,y$ that are natural, if $xy=n$ then $x$ or $y$ had to be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's read it from left to right first.

> $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \cdots$

The set of natural numbers $n$ such that ...

> $\cdots (n > 1) \wedge \cdots$

... $n$ is greater than $1$ and ...

> $\cdots (\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N})[ \dots$

... for all natural numbers $x,y$ ...

> $\cdots (xy=n) \Rightarrow \cdots$

... if $xy=n$, then ...

> $\cdots (x=1 \vee y=1)]\}$

... $x=1$ or $y=1$.

---

So it's the set of natural numbers $n$ which are greater than $1$ and satisfy the property that if you write them as a product of natural numbers, then one or the other of those natural numbers must be equal to $1$. But these are exactly the **prime numbers**!

Comment: Then I'm missing something fundamental here. Because the logic I see, which seems like is clearly wrong that n can be 6 (natural number greater than one which is not prime) because (xy=n) (1*6=6) which all of them are natural numbers (one of the condition) then (x or y) is 1, which is the other condition, can you please throw some more detail of the implications of why the equation is saying that these are primes.

Comment: @Morgoth: In order for $6$ to be in the set, it must be the case that *for all* pairs $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$, if $xy=6$ then $x=1$ or $y=1$. Sure, you've found a *single* pair $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ that makes it true; but there are pairs that don't, such as $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$. Hence the condition $(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N})[(xy=6) \Rightarrow (x=1 \vee y=1)]$ fails, and so $6$ is not an element of the set.

Comment: Ok, the thing I missed then it's the condition that it has to be **all pairs** that makes it impossible to find a divisor which is not 1 or the number itself, that's the bit I missed. Now it clicks and makes perfect sense, thank you very much for taking the time.